# How can I allow both ADFS/STS and Forms authentication in the same application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wif, adfs

I have an application that currently works only with Forms authentication, but now it will be exposed on the internet using HTTPS/SSL and in this case it needs to accept STS/ADFS authentication.

I followed the instructions from [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061.aspx), but how can I set my application to allow both authentication methods?

Web.config settings applied:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->

    <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</configSections>


<location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<authentication mode="None" />

<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />

        <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>

    <modules>
        <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
        <audienceUris>
            <add value="https://localhost:44300/Desvio/" />
        </audienceUris>
        <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <trustedIssuers>
                <add thumbprint="‎a527140bc9f440ebd6992ba26c6ea4758c3a2738" name="sts-dev.myserver.com" />
            </trustedIssuers>
        </issuerNameRegistry>
        <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://sts-dev.myserver.com/adfs/ls/" 
                    realm="https://localhost:44300/Desvio/" reply="https://localhost:44300/Desvio/" requireHttps="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: Did you ever succeed with [Wiktor Zychla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885118/107625)? Or did you go a completely other way?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, that should be fairly easy. The Forms Auth module is only about issuing a cookie for the local app and maintaining the session for currently logged user. It doesn't matter then how you obtain the authentication, by validating the username/password in your app or by accepting a SAML token.

Technically, remove both SAM and FAM modules from the pipeline. Make `Forms` your authentication method again so you have a regular forms auth based app.

Then, just add a code in your login endpoint that optionally accepts incoming SAML token from ADFS or any other STS. You could follow my tutorial

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html

The critical part of the code is surprisingly straightforward

```
var securityToken = fam.GetSecurityToken( request );

var config = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration
{
    CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
    IssuerNameRegistry   = new CustomIssuerNameRegistry()
};
config.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode = AudienceUriMode.Never;

var tokenHandler = new SamlSecurityTokenHandler
{
    CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
    Configuration        = config
};

// validate the token and get the ClaimsIdentity out of it
var identity  = tokenHandler.ValidateToken( securityToken );
```

As soon as you have the identity of the user from the incoming token, use Forms Auth to issue the very same cookie you would issue in a regular forms auth based app (note that in my tutorial I am issuing a SAM cookie here which is just another possibility you don't want to follow here since you insist specifically on forms cookies).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

With ADFS, you can have one or the other depending on the ADFS config.

There is an exception - if you have ADFS WAP, internal = WIA, External = FBA.

Or if an internal browser is not set for IWA, you get a popup login screen.

Comment: I suppose what you meant to say is that there is no "native" support, because I've found some articles showing ways to accomplish this auth. I just don't know if it works, but I'll give a try tomorrow. :). https://leastprivilege.com/2012/02/02/mixing-forms-and-token-authentication-in-a-single-asp-net-application/, http://blog.elis-co.com/wif-sso-and-forms-authentication-in-asp-net/

Comment: Cool - confusion of two concepts - ADFS FBA vs. ASP.NET Forms Authentication. I have seen that article in the past but couldn't get it working :-( IIRC, WIF by default protects the whole app.

Comment: The option using a custom attribute didn't work (breakpoints never hit), now I'll give a try at having a separate application for SSO that shares the auth cookie with the  main application.